# Trouble getting cronjob to work

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am having troubles getting a cronjob on ubuntu 16.04 digital ocean to work.

I programmed a python spider, which i want to run every 5 minutes. In order to run this spider I made a script runmyspider.sh (chmod +x) with the command:

```
scrapy runspider aspider.py
```

Now I want to call this script via Cron.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /scripts/runmyspider.sh 2>&1 /scripts/spider.log
```

However, the spider never runs (I can see that no changes in the database have been made, if I execute the file manually the changes happen)

What am I doing wrong here? I have set up a cron multiple times before, but this time I seem to get an error into it...

Thanks for all your advice!

Comment: What you see in `/var/log/cron.log` and `sysog`?

Comment: the spider. log file is empty?

Comment: Did you try to define the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev /var/log/cron.log doesnt exists, when i do cat syslog | grep "cron" I get:
Aug 24 17:17:01 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01 CRON[15149]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 24 18:17:01 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01 CRON[15700]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 24 19:17:01 ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01 CRON[16190]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Comment: @Gnudiff yes the log is empty :(

Comment: @spilia no i havent, how would i do that though? Add the path variable to the ~./profile  file?

Comment: Do you add cron record via `crontab -e` command or via creating a new file in `/etc/cron.d/` directory? And check that crond service is running by command `systemctl status crond`.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy I added it via crontab -e. service cron status says it is active

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use absolute paths to avoid problems.

`/bin/sh` (or /usr/bin/?)

`/usr/bin/scrapy` (or wherever it is, you can use `which scrapy` to find the binary)

and most importantly add script path for the aspider.py file for scrapy to use, I guess it could be `/scripts/aspider.py` ?

My first guess is that cron is running, finds sh, which finds scrapy which doesn't find the py file.

2. Don't overwrite the logfile, add to it:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /scripts/runmyspider.sh >> /scripts/spider.log 2>&1`

Comment: Alternatively you could do cd /scripts in the runmyspider.sh file, but that is generally not a very good idea.

Comment: I agree, using an absolute path is good, or you van put /usr/bin/ in the PATH.

Comment: /usr/bin/ can be expected to be in path, however, it is good practice nevertheless

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. I update the cronjob via crontab -e to: */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/scrapy /scripts/crawler.py >> /scripts/crawler.log 2>&1 .   still no result. service cron status says cron is running

Comment: @Tom why is it crawler.py if your initial post said it is aspider.py?

Comment: Also, do a "ls -l /scripts/" please, and tell under which user you are executing "crontab -e"